# Chakra UI - Input inside input not changing border color on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm making an input for a searchbar, with a button inside on the right side. I'm using Chakra UI - and I used the code provided on their website for INPUTS.

```
          <InputGroup 
              mr={4} 
              _hover={{ borderColor: 'red', border: '1px solid' }}>
            <Input 
              placeholder='Enter amount' 
              _hover={{ borderColor: 'red', border: '1px solid' }} />
            <InputRightElement
              bg='ZLGreen.50'
              border='1px solid'
              borderColor='gray.400'
              borderLeft='white'
              cursor='pointer'
              _hover={{ borderColor: 'red', border: '1px solid' }}
            >
              <Search2Icon color='green.500' />
            </InputRightElement>
          </InputGroup>
```

My problem is that each item has a separate hover property. I want the whole input bar to have the same border color on hover. I tried these things:

- I gave `<InputRightElement />` hover property that would change color to green border, however it only changed color if the user physically hovers over the small element.
- I also gave the whole `<InputGroup />` the same hover color, but it did not the match the border of the input. The border was way outside of the input.
- Finally, I also gave `<Input />` the same hover border - but it only
  changed the input alone, without the element on the right inheriting
  the border.

Is there any solution to this problem ?
On the left: light green
On the right: light gray

[image: What it looks like]